# How can I apply a CSS modification with a button

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I would like to apply a filter to an image (when I'm clicking a button)
and if I click another button it applies another filter.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

I've tried using the :active function in CSS but that just applies to the button. I've tried using javascript but it didn't work.

```
function FilterGrey() {
    var FilterGrey = Document.getElementsById("FilterGrey");
    document.body.video.filter = "grayscale(100%)"
}
```

Comment: where is your html code?!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? `document.body.video.filter = "grayscale(100%)"` What is document.body.video? Even if it did exist, you would be looking for `Node.style.filter` instead of `Node.filter`. Also, it sounds like you want to have multiple filter toggleable, you're going to need a bit more logic than that. Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]? Debugging questions require MCVE's to be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example done by toggling classes with JavaScript.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAAPrz

```js
function filter1() {
  document.getElementById('image').classList.toggle('filter1');
}
function filter2() {
  document.getElementById('image').classList.toggle('filter2');
}
```

```css
.filter1 {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
.filter2 {
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://mikeruiz.org/files/bliss-caf-newest.jpg" id="image">
<button onclick="filter1();">Filter 1</button>
<button onclick="filter2();">Filter 2</button>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :D But know how can i apply more than one filter?

Comment: You can apply multiple filters in sequence with the same `filter` property. Just chain one onto the end of the other. It would look like this: `filter: blur(10px) grayscale(50%);`

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this

```js
var FilterGrey = document.getElementById("FilterGrey");
var FilterOpacity = document.getElementById("FilterOpacity");
var FilterVideo = document.getElementById("FilteredImg");
FilterGrey.addEventListener('click', function(){
  FilterVideo.style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
});
FilterOpacity.addEventListener('click', function(){
  FilterVideo.style.filter = "opacity(40%)";
})
```

```css
#FilteredImg {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:20px
}
```

```html
<img id="FilteredImg" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/e8117f/fff">
<button id="FilterGrey">
Filter Grey
</button>
<button id="FilterOpacity">
Filter Opacity
</button>
```